# Magento - PHP explode getAttributeText

Tags: php, arrays, magento, explode

I need to get the value of an attribute for several Magento  products. The value is the width. So I am currently using:

```
$product->getAttributeText('width');
```

Which returns the correct value of say "100mm". I now need to get rid of the "mm" off the end, so I have tried:

```
explode('m',trim($width));
```

But this just returns "Array". I am guessing I need to convert the width value to a string first, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `echo explode('m',trim($width))[0];` or `$t = explode('m',trim($width)); echo $t[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you get something other than mm. If I were you, would use preg_replace.

```
$widthAtt = $product->getAttributeText('width');
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $widthAtt);
```

What it does is, it removes any numeric values from $widthAtt.